# How do I get "My APK" app to find my APKS file

Tags: apk, bluestacks

I have installed [My APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andatsoft.myapk.fwa) app on BlueStacks. It is very small but just barely readable.

I enabled its access to the local computer. The app is supposed to handle APKS, but in the APKS tab, it says no APK file found. I tried looking in the scan folder but it is unclear where it is actually searching in regard to Download.

How do I get "My APK" app to find my APKS file?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to ask. You should edit your question and give more details what you are trying to do. In case the question is about a self-developer app please use stackoverflow.com as development questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It is App usage question. Some sent me a APKS file and I can't open it.